# Kivy virtual keyboard not showing

Tags: python, kivy, virtual-keyboard

I have a Kivy app which I have developed on my MacBook Pro Retina running OS X 10.9.2, Kivy 1.8.0 and Python 2.7.

The production environment is a PC running Windows 7, Kivy 1.8.0 and Python 2.7. It has six screens.

In my config I have set the following:

```
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'systemandmulti')
```

When my app loads on my Mac I see the following in the log output:

```
virtual keyboard allowed, multiuser mode, not docked
```

When my app loads on the Windows machine I see the following in the log output:

```
virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
```

I do not know what is different on the Windows machine where it would not allow the virtual keyboard. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved this issue by making config the very first thing I did in the app, i.e.:

main.py

```
# config
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'systemandmulti')
```